# Hide qTips on both distance and click event

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide, qtip2

I want my qtips to hide on both events: click and distance :20, here is my code:

```
hide : {                                                    
    distance : 20,
},
```

If I put instead of distance:20 -> event : 'click', it works fine on click, but if I added both just the click is gonna work!! Can I use both??

I tried using this:

```
hide : {
    event: 'click',         
    distance : 20,
},
```

But as I said only the click works then!

Comment: Obviously `event: 'click'` disables hover and motion event effects. Did you consider showing on click and hiding on distance?

Comment: I want it to hide on both events and show on hover after 500ms delay, like if you have a button with tooltip on it, you need to show the tip on hover, and if you clicked it or gone away from it, hide it.